# Django NoReverseMatch at /qw-1/

Tags: python, django

Im new to django and was **struck by using slug**, now Im confused how to **use the ID parameter and convert to slug**

URL.py

```
 url(r'^deletePost/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.delete_post, name='delete_post')
```

Template

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_post' id=post.id %}">{% csrf_token %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> &nbsp Delete</button>
</form>
```

Views.py

```
def delete_post(request,slug):
    posts=Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        posts.delete()
        return redirect("home")
```

How can i use slug & id to delete the post which is created

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Error for reference
[image]

Comment: Try changing [\w-] to [-\w]

Comment: It's not clear if you want to require both `slug` and `id`. Or if you accept either `slug` or `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opionion, you dont want to convert the id to slug. You can just make your application flexible enough so that you could delete by either `slug` or `id`. You just need to handle the parameters accordingly.

So, you can do something like this:

urls.py

```
url(r'^deletePost/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.delete_post, name='delete_post_by_slug'),
url(r'^deletePost/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_post, name='delete_post_by_id')
```

And in the views:

```
def delete_post(request, slug=None, id=None):
    if slug:
        posts=Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if id:
        posts=Post.objects.get(id=id)
    #Now, your urls.py would ensure that this view code is executed only when slug or id is specified

    #You might also want to check for permissions, etc.. before deleting it - example who created the Post, and who can delete it.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        posts.delete()
        return redirect("home")
```

Note that you can compress the 2 URL patterns into a single one - but this approach keeps it readable, and understandable. I shall let you figure out the URL consolidation once you are comfortable with the django framework, etc..

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that you need to update the url name in the template tag: `{% url 'delete_post_by_id' id=post.id %}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use both slug and id, your URL pattern should look like this:

```
url(r'^deletePost/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)-(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$',
    views.delete_post, name='delete_post')
```

And your view should look like this:

```
def delete_post(request, **kwargs):
    # Here kwargs value is {'slug': 'qw', 'id': '1'}
    posts = Post.objects.get(**kwargs)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        posts.delete()
        return redirect('home')
    # ... (I guess this view does not end here)
```

And your template also have to set both:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_post' slug=post.id id=post.id %}">{% csrf_token %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> &nbsp Delete</button>
</form>
```