# Django Convert ID to slug

Tags: python, django

Im new to django and wanted to **convert id/pk to slug**, I wanted to make **url to be friendly or easy to understand**

Wanted to make url  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`

Model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comments=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def description_as_list(self):
        return self.description.split('\n')
```

admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['title','description']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    class Meta:
        model = Post

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(),name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog_post.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    paginate_by = 2

def detail(request, id):
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, "blog_detail.html", {'posts': posts,})
```

Templates

```
{% for threads in object_list  %}
    <p class="blog-post-title"><a href="{% url 'detail' slug=threads.id %}">{{ threads.title }}</a></p>
    <hr />
{% endfor %}
```

Following **error** is obtained by doing so...What more changes to be 
[image]

Any help is appreciated to make url readable. Thanks in davance

Comment: Your view, takes and id, while your URL pattern takes a slug.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard..What changes to be done..

Comment: You should find out yourself. Or you will ask quite the same question tomorrow, as you asked quite the same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092955/django-noreversematch-at-qw-1

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you need to pass the slug parameter to the detail function of views.py like this:

```
def detail(request, slug):
    posts = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, "blog_detail.html", {'posts': posts,})
```

Moreover, your blog_post.html template should accept the slug in the url like this:

```
{% for threads in object_list  %}
    <p class="blog-post-title"><a href="{% url 'detail' slug=threads.slug %}">{{ threads.title }}</a></p>
    <hr />
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, you need to have a blog_detail template for the detail view.